# How fast should the Googe Places API return results on 8.62 Mbps download speed?

Tags: php, jquery, performance, google-places-api, google-geocoding-api

I keep averaging at 800ms but Im receiving 10 results. I did notice while using the Google Geocode API I did get a faster speed at 76ms but thats only returning one result. Just wanted to make sure if that was ok at 8.62Mbps internet speed.

Im using jquery ajax for this setup. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd likely get roughly the same speed on a connection that was twice as fast or half as fast as your connection.

For results from APIs like this one, it's not the data speed that primarily matters. The issue is the speed with which the API gets results from its database.

Comment: Thanks for that. I tested it on a different internet speed and your right. It was almost the same.